# Python Regex: How to extract string between parentheses and quotes if they exist

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the value/argument of each trigger in Jenkinsfiles between the parentheses and the quotes if they exist.

For example, given the following:

```
upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)  # just parentheses
pollSCM('H * * * *')     # single quotes and parentheses
```

Desired result respectively:

```
upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
H * * * *
```

My current result:

```
upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
H * * * *'        # Notice the trailing single quote
```

So far I have been successful with the first trigger (upstream one), but not for the second one (pollSCM) because there's still a trailing single quote.

After the group `(.+)`, it doesn't capture the trailing single quote with `\'*`, but it does capture the close parenthesis with `\)`. I could simply use .replace() or .strip() to remove it, but what is wrong with my regex pattern? How can I improve it? Here's my code:

```
pattern = r"[A-Za-z]*\(\'*\"*(.+)\'*\"*\)"
text1 = r"upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)"
text2 = r"pollSCM('H * * * *')"
trigger_value1 = re.search(pattern, text1).group(1)
trigger_value2 = re.search(pattern, text2).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = """upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)  # just parentheses
pollSCM('H * * * *')"""
print(re.findall("\((.*?)\)", s))
```

**Output:**

```
["upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS", "'H * * * *'"]
```

Comment: The output still have parentheses around them and the second still has single quotes around them

Comment: Updated to remove the parentheses. To remove the quotes you can use `str.replace("'", "")`

Answer (score 1):

Your `\'*` part of it means `0 or more matches` for your single tick so the `.+` will grab the last `'` because it's greedy.  You need to add the `?` to `(.+)` for it to not be greedy.  Basically it means to grab everything until it comes across the `'`.

This pattern will work for you:
`[A-Za-z]*\(\'*\"*(.+?)\'*\"*\)`

[UPDATE]

To answer your question below I'll just add it here.

`So the ? will make it not greedy up until the next character indicated in the pattern?`

Yes, it basically changes repetition operators to not be greedy (lazy quantifier) because they are greedy by default.  So `.*?a` will match everything until the first `a` while `.*a` will match everything including any `a` found in the string until it can't match against the string anymore.  So if your string is `aaaaaaaa` and your regex is `.*?a` it will actually match every `a`.  As an example, if you use `.*?a` with a substitution of `b` for every match on string `aaaaaaaa` you will get the string `bbbbbbbb`. `.*a` however on string `aaaaaaaa` with same substitution will return a single `b`.

Here's a link that explains the different quantifier types (greedy, lazy, possessive): http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html

Comment: This solution was simple and spot on. It corrected the problem in the regex pattern. So the ? will make it not greedy up until the next character indicated in the pattern?

Comment: @VirenMody - I answered your question above.  If you found this acceptable, please upvote and mark as the answer. :)

Comment: I did as soon I tried it, but I don't have enough reputation yet for it to be displayed that's why I commented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For you example data your could make the `'` optional `'?` and capture your values in a group and then loop through the captured groups.

[`\('?(.*?)'?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/eMVMRn/2)

```
test_str = ("upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)  # just parentheses\n"
    "pollSCM('H * * * *')     # single quotes and parentheses")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1  
        print (match.group(groupNum))
```

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/ZCET17209)

That would give you:

```
upstreamProjects: 'upstreamJob', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
H * * * *
```

To get a more strict match you could use an alternation to match between `()` or `('')` but not with a single `'` like  `('H * * * *)` and then loop through the captured groups. Because you now capture 2 groups where 1 of the 2 is empty you could check that you only retrieve a non empty group.

[`\((?:'(.*?)'|([^'].*?[^']))\)`](https://regex101.com/r/eMVMRn/1)

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/UAFM37409)